# QByteArray conversion in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
QByteArray x;

x[0] = 0xAA; 
qDebug() << QString::number(x[0] , 16);
```

i saw `ffffffffffffffaa` in debug screen. I think `QBteArray` is signed char. So how can I store this data in `QByteArray` properly or how can I convert and save data to an unsigned variable?

Comment: 1. Probably you need to use `QVector<unsigned int>`

Comment: 2. Another way is to use cast `static_cast<unsigned int>(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

The data are stored correctly, you can check that by printing the contents of the array `x` directly without using `QString::number` (i.e. `qDebug() << x;`), this should output: `"\xAA"`.

The reason for your unexpected output is that there are [7 overloads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number) for `QString::number`, all of them differ in the type of the first argument. The supported types are `long`, `uint`, `int`, `uint`, `qlonglong`, `qulonglong` and `double`. All of the overloads that deal with integral types are [implemented by](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp?h=5.8#n6705) calling either `return number(qlonglong(n), base);` or `return number(qulonglong(n), base);`.

That is why the `char` you are passing to `QString::number` gets treated as a `qlonglong` (i.e. `x[0] = 0xAA` which means `x[0] = -86`, then this value is converted to a `qlonglong` hence `QString::number` returns `ffffffffffffffaa`).